# Read String without defining length

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, 32-bit, irvine32

Is it possible to read a string using (call ReadString) without defining the length of the string which will be read? Before I call ReadString I must say how long the string will be:

```
mov edx, offset StringOffset
mov ecx, maxLenght
call ReadString                             
mov countOfChars, eax
```

Is there any way to read a string without defining max length?

Comment: _"Is it possible to Read String using (call ReadString) without define length of String witch will be read? "_ That sounds dangerous. What if you read more data than the buffer can hold?

Answer (score 0):

I never made it with a ReadString call, but you can use the `\0` at end of string to have the `maxLength` or read it mannually ?

```
    xor     eax, eax
    cmp     edi, 0
    jz      end
deb:
    cmp     BYTE[edi+eax], 0
    jz      end
    inc     eax
    jmp     deb
end:
    ...
```